# Metro modern UI for xaml

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, modern-ui

I want to design my xaml user control in metro style and want to use controls like tiles etc which are missing from usual XAML toolbox. How do I use these controls ? Are there any packages or library which allows us with modern UI metro controls to be directly used with XAML ?

Comment: take a look at MahApps metro http://mahapps.com/

Comment: I have tried MahApps, but i am developing a visual studio extension. And then the extension opens up a window which has a user control. It does not suppor windows or pages, just user control. I am not sure how to use MahApps with user controls as I do not have Window control to apply style on that.

Comment: May be you should start with small changes. Lear a little bit about VS Extension model - *how* you can change it, *where* to change it, debugging, etc... and then you could continue to MahApps Metro (you should understand it too - it's not so easy `Template`

Comment: debugging and changing extensions is not a problem, but the tool windows developed by the extension renders inside a user control. And we cannot nest window inside a user control. That is why I am unable to apply MetroWindow style to it. As MetroWindow style can only be applied to a window not user control.

Comment: @danvy Yes its developed in WPF

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use native WinRT visual components in a WPF project. You will have to rely on custom controls/styles. You can do it by yourself or you can use some third party librairies like Open Source [Modern UI for WPF](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui) or [Materiel Design in XML](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) or use commercial components set like [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/)

Comment: HI. Yes I am using a 3rd party Nuget package. The problem is that the 3rd party dll is not getting deployed with the Visual Studio extension. I dont know how to package the requied 3rd party dlls

Comment: You could include the required source in your project

Comment: Didn't think of that. Thanks. Will give it a try. But the problem is I would not be able to get automatic updates. Will have to update thee code manually every-time.

Comment: You can automate things with a git script

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. I actually investigated more and found out that the dlls are getting copied, but for some reasons, my extension is unable to reference them. Will have to find out what are the locations the extension is looking up for the dlls.